# Unexplained Opsview configuration error

Tags: troubleshooting, opsview

Somehow I've broken by Opsview configuration, and it gives me a completely unhelpful error: `critical   2010-10-12 12:09:57 Cannot reload:`.  It looks like there should be more info, but there's not.

I tried undoing the change I made, and then I tried restoring the previous backup, tried restarting opsview but it always says the same thing.

I've checked

- /usr/local/nagios/var/nagios.log
- /var/log/messages
- /var/log/secure
- /var/log/opsview/opsview-web.log
- /var/log/opsview/opsviewd.log

and haven't been able to find any indication of what the problem is.  Does anyone know where else I could look or have an idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovered what my problem was: opsviewd wasn't running (checked with `/usr/local/nagios/bin/opsviewd status`).  Started with `service opsview start` and ran `chkconfig --add opsview` and everything is back to normal.